# How to vote to keep a question open?

Tags: support, vote-to-close

There's [a question](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/298083/what-could-we-see-if-we/298279#298279) that currently has 3 close votes. I think it's a good question and would like to vote to leave it open, and I don't know how.

When I see questions in the close votes queue, there's the option to "Leave Open", which subtracts one number from the close votes. However, if I click the "Close (3)" link on the question page, there's no option for me to leave it open, only options on how to vote to close it. I looked through the close votes queue and it never came up.

Is there another way to vote to leave a question open?

Comment: You could always wait for it to be closed then cast a vote to reopen it. If you do that ideally leave a comment saying why you think it should be reopened to prime visitors to the reopen queue.

Answer (score 2):

I think the best way you can go about keeping a question open is to review it in [the close queue](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/close). Currently at 4k+ rep, you have enough rep that grants you access to that queue and the [privilege](https://ell.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) to cast close/keep open/reopen votes on questions.

> Reviewing close and reopen votes
>
> Any post which currently has an active close vote or a close flag will appear in the Close Votes review queue. In this queue, users can either vote to close the question, edit the question, or recommend leaving it open. **Edits or a sufficient number of "Leave Open" reviews will remove the question from review and immediately begin aging the close votes.** If the question receives another close vote after being kicked out, it will re-enter the queue for further review. Questions with vote to close as a duplicate will also list each possible duplicate in a tab at the top for easy reviewing.

The "a sufficient number" part sounds vague, but [I am led to believe currently the number is 3](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/139836/451368). That is, if three people have reviewed that question and voted to leave it open, it will be removed from the close queue. But it could still be closed when others see that question and cast enough close votes.

Alternatively, you can vote to reopen it once it gets closed.

Comment: Someone could also try to improve the question to make it clearer that it is not off-topic, or to highlight in the comments why the question shouldn't be closed. On ELL, it is sometimes hard to understand what the question is asking because of the language barrier, and if someone else shares their perspective in the comments it can help others see why it should stay open.

Comment: I mentioned above that this particular question didn't show up when I looked through my close queue. I don't know why. Perhaps not everyone has access to all the questions in the queue? Either way, this wasn't an option for me.

Comment: @gotube Since you didn't link a specific question, I don't know what the problem might be. Happy to look into it if you include a link to that question.

Comment: @EddieKal link added. It's flagged as a dupe, but I don't think the linked question answers the OP's question

Comment: @gotube It's [still in the review queue](https://ell.stackexchange.com/review/close/126917) as of this moment.

Comment: @EddieKal Thanks! Then, I guess my question is: is there a way to jump to a question's page in the close review queue other than skipping through the whole thing? Skipping has the side effect of hiding all the skipped ones, and I'd prefer not to do that, if possible

Comment: @gotube Visit the **close** reviews **history** tab and search for the post you are interested in saving. If another user has reviewed that question, it will be displayed. However, I don't know if the history page is visible to any one who has earned the *privilege* of reviewing questions, a certain rep threshold might be a requirement. In any case, that's my shortcut.

Comment: I do have access to it, thanks @Mari-LouA

Comment: @gotube do you see *all* the reviews submitted by users or only the ones you have completed? For example, do you see my recommendation to leave open  a different post?

Comment: Where do you mean? In the "Review tasks" tab or "History" tab, or??

Comment: @gotube When you click on the history tab of the close reviews, do you see a page with a list of all the recently reviewed questions by "everyone" or do you see just a list of your reviews. P.S You need to ping me every time. I am not the author of this post, so I don't receive a notification. PPS sorry boss (Eddie) for  the flurry of pings in your inbox! ☺

Comment: @Mari-LouA gotube will only see their own actions in history.

Comment: @mdewey because they don't have the necessary rep. I thought that might be the case...a distant memory in the antechamber of my mind.